# Join two tables cms/page and cms/page_store

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, join

I will try get all pages assign to the website with name

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection();
$collection->getSelect()
   ->join(
       array('cps' => $collection->getTable('cms/page_store')),
       'cps.page_id = main_table.page_id',
       array('store_id')
   );
```

but after the query I receive on my page such message

> Item (Mage_Cms_Model_Page) with the same id "9" already exist

as a result I want receive something like that

```
About Us    about-magento-demo-store    2 columns with right bar    All Store Views Enabled Mar 13, 2015 1:30:07 AM Mar 13, 2015 1:30:07 AM
...
```

Answer (score 2):

This actually already happens from within the collection you are assembling.  This is why you are receiving the error.

If you look in `app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Model/Resource/Page/Collection.php` there is a method called `_afterLoad()`.  This is where the joining of the table is done.  This method is a hook method called when loading collections.  It also happens on resources as well.

Here is the `_afterLoad()` method:

```
/**
     * Perform operations after collection load
     *
     * @return Mage_Cms_Model_Resource_Page_Collection
     */
    protected function _afterLoad()
    {
        if ($this->_previewFlag) {
            $items = $this->getColumnValues('page_id');
            $connection = $this->getConnection();
            if (count($items)) {
                $select = $connection->select()
                        ->from(array('cps'=>$this->getTable('cms/page_store')))
                        ->where('cps.page_id IN (?)', $items);

                if ($result = $connection->fetchPairs($select)) {
                    foreach ($this as $item) {
                        if (!isset($result[$item->getData('page_id')])) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        if ($result[$item->getData('page_id')] == 0) {
                            $stores = Mage::app()->getStores(false, true);
                            $storeId = current($stores)->getId();
                            $storeCode = key($stores);
                        } else {
                            $storeId = $result[$item->getData('page_id')];
                            $storeCode = Mage::app()->getStore($storeId)->getCode();
                        }
                        $item->setData('_first_store_id', $storeId);
                        $item->setData('store_code', $storeCode);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return parent::_afterLoad();
    }
```

I hope this helps.